# Find exact difference between two values in Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

If we have a normal distribution of N(10,2) and we are asked on what is the proportion of values betwen 7 and 8 we can calculate this by:

```
F(8) = NORM.DIST(8,10,2,TRUE) = 15.9%
F(7) = NORM.DIST(7,10,2,TRUE) = 6.7%
F(8) - F(7) = 9.2%
```

Is there a way to calculate F(x) and F(y) so that F(x) - F(y) = 10%?

Comment: There are infinitely many pairs $(x, y)$ satisfying that equation. You can fix any $x$ and find a corresponding $y$. You'll need some other property if you want a unique solution.

Comment: You have a typo or a misinterpretation. If the standard deviation is $2$ then the normal distribution is $\mathcal N(10,2^2)=\mathcal N(10,4)$ Or the other way round. If the normal distribution is $\mathcal N(10,2)$ then the standard deviation is $\sqrt 2$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should of used N(10,4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Then $P(X\leq x+x')-P(X\leq x)=F(x+x')-F(x)=c$

In your case $c=0.1$. For a **given** $x$ the equality can be arranged to $F(x+x')=c+F(x)$.

$c+F(x)=r$ is a real value between  $0$ and $1$.

$F(x+x')=r$

$x+x'=F^{-1}(r)$

$x'=F^{-1}(r)-x$

For a given $x$ the value of $x'$ is $F^{-1}(r)-x$

Comment: Let’s say that x = 8, for what I understand then r= c+F(x) = 0.1 + 0.159 = 0.259. I’m not sure how to proceed to calculate x’. How do you compute F−1(r)

Comment: It depends wether you use a table or a calculator. If you use a table you firstly have to standardized the random variable $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. What do you use?

Comment: If you use a calculator you use the function $=\text{norminv}(0.25866,10,2)=8.705$ This is the inverse function of the cdf. I have used the more exact value.

Comment: Callculus, it is great, it works. I'm using a calculator. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: NIce that it works. You´re welcome.